# Custom UIView - autolayout not applied

Tags: ios, uiview, autolayout, xib

My registration scene has a custom UIView on the scene. There are autolayout constraints applied as per the following screen. The yellow indicates the custom view.
[image]

The custom view is set in identity inspector to `RegisterView`. The `RegisterView` class simply loads a XIB:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("RegisterUserView", owner: self, options: nil)
}
```

The XIB has autolayout applied so as it renders as follows:

[image]

However, when I run the application it appears that autolayout constraints haven't been applied:

[image]

Do I need to add code to force the layout constraints to apply?

Comment: You have applied constraints to child views of your Custom View, but when you add this view to another view lets say to your ViewController's view then you need to apply constraint on this customView object also, so that i can layout itself with respect to it's parent view.

Answer (score 0):

I tried something like the below and it worked

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        self.customSubView = CustomView1.loadFromNibNamed("CustomView") as! CustomView1

        customSubView.frame = _CustomSubView.frame 
        customSubView.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        self._CustomSubView.addSubview(customSubView)
    }
```

Hope it helps